# Grails check list for value in map

Tags: groovy

Is there an easy syntax or convenience method (without looping by myself) for checking to see if a value exists in a `Map` which is in a `List`? For example what I am trying to do is:

```
​def myList = []
myList.push([first: "John", last: "Doe"])
println myList.contains(it -> it.first == "John")
```

should print true but syntax is incorrect. Basically, I need to know if the list contains a map such that in that map the value of the "first" key is "John".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using find may be a better solution:

```
def myList = [] 
myList.push([first: "John", last: "Doe"])

def exists = (myList.find{ it -> it.first == 'John'}​​​​​ ? true : false)

assert exists == true

exists = ​(myList.find{ it -> it.first == 'Jane'} ? true : false)

assert exists == false​
```

Comment: @Johsua Moore If the statement def exists = (myList.find{ it -> it.first == it.uniqueId}​​​​​ ? true : false) were in a list iterating loop and I wanted to refer to the 'it' in the outer scope, could I rename the inner scope 'it' in the given statement to something else and then it.uniqueId would automatically refer to the outer scope 'it'?

Comment: I would rename them both to be safe. (:

Comment: I can't figure out my exactly needed variation of one of your code lines above results in compilation error. Here is what I have `def exists = (existingIndRecs.find{ existant -> existant.uniqueId == incomingRecord.uniqueId}​​​​​ ? true : false)` and here is the error I get: Compilation Error: startup failed:
/home/ec2-user/FatcaOne/grails-app/services/com/twc/fatcaone/FileImportService.groovy: 184: expecting ')', found '​​​​​' @ line 184, column 100.
   Id == incomingRecord.uniqueId}​​​​​ ? tr

Comment: Not sure why you would be getting that. I mocked up this http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5752142325350400 so you can compare it to what you have. You may want to post a new question if you are still having issues.

Answer (score 4):

Another simpler check could be using spread operator as below

```
assert 'John' in myList*.first
```

**UPDATE**
Benchmarking the performance between usage of `find` and `in` provides result that incline towards usage of `in` if list size is small.

[**Refer and run this GIST**](https://gist.github.com/dmahapatro/0a4b785c80f11ee5dab1). Results may vary, but it is surprising that `in` consumes less CPU consistently against `find` when the list size is small (as shown in question, refer first result). Below is the set of results recorded as I write this update.

```
                                              user  system      cpu     real

findTestWithSmallerListSize                    571       0      571      598
inListTestWithSmallerListSize                  411       0      411      411

findTestWithMatchPresentInEnd              2714872      43  2714915  2739768
inListTestWithMatchPresentInEnd            2266303      39  2266342  2431595

findTestWithMatchPresentInAverageCenter    2141836      39  2141875  2263714
inListTestWithMatchPresentInAverageCenter  2261387      37  2261424  2438485

findTestWithMatchPresentInFirst            1667364      27  1667391  1813254
inListTestWithMatchPresentInFirst          2288471      37  2288508  2425089
```

Based on the above result I agree that if the match is present in the beginning or towards the beginning of the list (4th result from above) then `find` is fully efficient.

Comment: This is going to be less efficient than using `find` because this is going to visit every element in myList, retrieve the `first` property from each of them, put all of those in a new `List` and then search that `List` for "John".  Using `find` isn't going to create that intermediary `List` and isn't going to necessarily visit every element in the initial `List`.  `find` will stop as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I would agree if the match is found early while iteration. But the result shows otherwise when I [**benchmark all the cases**](https://gist.github.com/dmahapatro/0a4b785c80f11ee5dab1). Please validate.

Comment: @AnonymousHuman For smaller lists, performance would be negligible and would not matter. If that is the case and you are dealing with list with small size then I don't think there should be any performance problem using as above answer and as per the benchmark. I would still use `find` if dealing with humongous list though.

Comment: "Please validate".  Those kind of benchmarks aren't particularly interesting.  That test can be reorganized in such a way to indicate a bigger difference.  See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/1a30d1c1b23d2fd4ee9d. For the 4 cases 2 are very close and the other 2 are dramatically slanted against using the spread operator. I don't suggest that is really valid argument one way or the other. It isn't. This really isn't a big deal. I shouldn't even have mentioned it. I used poor judgement and I apologize for getting involved. All the best.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I just wanted to validate if you were getting similar results in benchmark. I agree with use of find as compared to in list. M glad this comparison has been brought up. Never meant to offend your opinion. :)

Comment: I added a longer comment at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57228/groovy-find-v-spread clarifying what I was getting at.